# Is there a way to set the max width of a column when displaying JSONB results in psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a problem that is somewhat similar to this question: [Is there a way to set the max width of a column when displaying query results in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272328/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-max-width-of-a-column-when-displaying-query-results-in). I have a number of tables in Postgres with large JSONB documents. When I use psql from Emacs, it grinds to a halt trying to display fields with these documents. Ideally, I just want to see the first X characters of a document when I `select *` from a given table. I tried:

```
\pset columns 20
```

To no avail. Is there some permutation of `columns` and `format` that could achieve this? At present I am manually casting columns like so:

```
cast("PAYLOAD" as varchar(50))
```

This works, but it does mean I need to remember to cast before selecting which is a major pain.