# PostgreSQL CLI set max colum width

Tags: postgresql, terminal

How to set maximum column width for postgresql query result in the Linux terminal?

I know you can use:
`\pset format wrapped`
`\pset columns 20`
But it doesn't work when the output contains two columns like in this example:
`select 'some long long long long text', 'some other long long long text';`

Comment: It works fine for me.  Please describe what you wanted to happen and what happened instead.

Comment: @jjanes I figured out that pager isn't a problem. It works when i use "select 'some long text';" like in the example i found in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272328/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-max-width-of-a-column-when-displaying-query-results-in. But when I add the second column "select 'some long text', 'some other long text';" column width restriction is ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around a little bit, I think you are running afoul of [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> Note that psql will not attempt to wrap column header titles; therefore, wrapped format behaves the same as aligned if the total width needed for column headers exceeds the target.

Since your default column headers are 8 characters, plus (with the default settings) a mandatory white space before and after and a mandatory pipe character between them, that gives 21 columns. So it reverts to not wrapping.

Comment: Oh, so this doesn't set the maximum width for individual columns, but for the entire table. I missunderstood that command. So is there a way to set max width for all columns separately? For me, I just want to set a limitation on the second column, but setting a max width 20 for every column would be good enough.

Comment: Right it is the total width.  I don't know how to manage it per column, you would probably need to write your own client.  To set it the same for each column, i think you would just need to set the total to 20 * number of columns (plus some for the separators), which is not convenient as you would need to count the columns of each query and reset between each one.